# Configuring Java contextPath to accept dynamic value

Tags: java, spring, rest, hateoas, contextpath

I am trying to configure a context path for an API in a way that best leverages the features of Spring Data Rest. The way the API is designed ensures a client can only ever see the records belonging to them and no other clients. As such, the base URL is similar to `"/root/employer/{employerId}"`.

I am trying to set the context path in the main class with `System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/root/employer/{employerId}")`. Based on my limited understanding, however, since the context path is a String, this is being rendered in Postman as `"/root/employer/%7BemployerId%7D"` as opposed to the desired format, and is therefore not recognizing actual IDs when they are passed in.

Is there a known way to resolve this? Alternatively, is there a better approach to this dilemma altogether?

Comment: That won't work as the context root needs to be a fixed String and cannot contain path variables.

Comment: Ah, thanks @M. Deinum, I was beginning to strongly suspect this myself. Are there any alternative approaches you can recommend?